# Stop Script Execution if USE [database] Fails in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

Typically in a SQL Server script I will have a USE [database] statement at the start.  This would be for a Schema Table creation script for example.

The script is assuming that the database already exists.  However, to prevent accidentally running the script against a master database, I just want the script to terminate execution.

So error checking and try...catch does not work.

**Error Check**

```
USE [MYDATABASE]

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Cannot find database so skipping script creation', 1, 1);
    GOTO AbortScript
END

...

AbortScript:
    PRINT 'Aborted!'
```

**Try Catch**

```
BEGIN TRY
    USE [MYDATABASE]
    PRINT 'xxxx'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT 'OOps Errored'

END CATCH
```

Can you trap these errors?  I am currently using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the database exists first:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'mydatabase')) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Cannot find database so skipping script creation', 1, 1);
    GOTO AbortScript
END;

USE [MYDATABASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to abort a large SQL script that includes many batches (marked with "GO"). Unfortunately you can't use a GOTO block, IF block, or TRY-CATCH to skip multiple batches, but you can turn off command execution, which has the same effect.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'MyTable')
     SET NOEXEC ON
```

(Don't forget to SET NOEXEC OFF at the end of your script)

[Detailed reference here](https://sqlhints.com/2015/05/23/how-to-stop-or-abort-or-break-the-execution-of-the-statements-in-the-current-batch-and-in-the-subsequent-batches-separated-by-go-statement-based-on-some-condition-in-sql-server/).